# search first element under itself using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to select multiple checkboxes when previous one is checked.
Currently the first set of checkboxes is working fine. But when I select second checkbox the attached checkboxes should be selected instead of the first checkbox set.

**html code**

```
<acronym>
    <input name="" type="checkbox" class="OverFlowCheckbox" value="">
    <div class="Selectionlist">
    <div class="percentageBox color2"> </div><span>Hus og hjem</span></div>
    <div class="_user_auth">
    <ul class="selectCheckBox">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="checkbox1" class="css-label lite-red-check">Boligalarm</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="checkbox2" class="css-label lite-red-check">Forsikring</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="checkbox3" class="css-label lite-red-check">Lån</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="checkbox5" class="css-label lite-red-check">Eiend. megler</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox6" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="checkbox6" class="css-label lite-red-check">Telecom</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="checkbox4" class="css-label lite-red-check">Varmepumpe</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="checkbox5" class="css-label lite-red-check">Annet</label></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </acronym> 
    <acronym>
    <input name="" type="checkbox" class="OverFlowCheckbox" value="">
     <div class="Selectionlist">
    <div class="percentageBox color3"></div><span>Bil og båt</span></div>
    <div class="_user_auth">
    <ul class="selectCheckBox">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="checkbox1" class="css-label lite-red-check">Bilverksted</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="checkbox2" class="css-label lite-red-check">Båtverksted</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="checkbox3" class="css-label lite-red-check">Dekk</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="checkbox5" class="css-label lite-red-check">Annet bil</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox6" class="css-checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="checkbox6" class="css-label lite-red-check">Annet båt</label></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </acronym>
```

**java script code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('acronym .OverFlowCheckbox').click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 


     $('._user_auth').first().fadeIn('slow');
    } 
        else 
    {
    $('._user_auth ').fadeOut('slow');
     }
    });
});
```

[current online jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/mvWwD/5/)

Comment: You can use jquery `.next()` to target the next element. Or the `.child()` or `.children()` to get one or more children.

Comment: there is a whole section of API for traversal methods. Start there and look at examples for each

Comment: Your code is working exactly as intended.

Comment: @pankaj tiwari Checkout my answer below, using $(this).parent().find(). Let me know if that didn't get your job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $(this).parent().find('._user_auth') to find the list under the current element.

[JSFiddle demo of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/mvWwD/11/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('acronym .OverFlowCheckbox').click(function () {
        var chkList = $(this).parent().find('._user_auth').first();
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            chkList.fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            chkList.fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse to closest element `acronym` and then find `div._user_auth` in it  :

```
$('acronym .OverFlowCheckbox').click(function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 
    $(this).closest('acronym').find('._user_auth').fadeIn('slow');
} else {
    $(this).closest('acronym').find('._user_auth').fadeOut('slow');
}});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/buqskdw3/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('acronym .OverFlowCheckbox').click(function(){

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) { 

            $(this).next().next().fadeIn('slow');

        } else {

            $(this).next().next().fadeOut('slow');

        }

   });

});
```

Comment: Can you pls add more description to the question?